# Eclipse does not recognize java package

Tags: java, eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I added my java project to github using the git plugin in eclipse. I even added src directory and committed.
After I committed The programs says that that class User which is in the package in.jcap.sanctuary.pojo is not a type.

I restarted the project many times, but after committing to the git repository if I create any new class in eclipse I get the same error as above.
I get the following error
"An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. in.jcap.sanctuary.pojo.User resolves to a package"

Comment: Do you have problem in code commit? Elaborate.

Comment: pks I don't have any problems while committing.

Comment: This also happens with any version control I use bazaar or git. Could this be a problem with me committing the src directory

Comment: The source code is available at https://github.com/alwindoss84/Sanctuary.git
you can take a look at the project

Comment: commiting via git or eclipse svn?

Comment: Done with the code , when do you get problem while commiting the package?

Comment: I am committing via eclipse git plugin

Comment: When I run the project using the apache tomcat server 7.02 I get the error I mentioned in the question

Comment: ok then do one thing configure your eclipse svn and use the repository path of github, and the commit via eclipse svn you are done.

Comment: I have to use svn to check into git hub??? is that possible??

Comment: It is ofcorse. [link]http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/installation-instructions.php use this link to configure it.

Comment: It is not working I am getting an error with the URL

Comment: go through the url it is working. And don't try use it within install new software ... this is the instructions page.

Comment: In the link you have sent there is no other way of installing svn other than the "install new software" way

Comment: well this would be the most appropriate one. Do it I am here to guide you further.

Comment: Why use SVN to commit to github? Does the project execute correctly before you commit to github?

Comment: @pKs I installed the svn. Then I clicked on Team->Share Project anc chose svn in svn for the url I specified https://github.com/alwindoss84/Sanctuary.git then when I said finish I got this error:
Share project was failed.
svn: Malformed URL '/alwindoss84/Sanctuary.git/!svn/wbl/50956e70-3801-0010-b3ba-497abab23d51/6'

Comment: click open perspective > svn repositories and then checkout the project from the git ... using the url you checked in the project through git command line

Comment: @AlwinDoss did you try a Project>Clean and clean your workspace?

Comment: I figured the problem, I had a lot of jars related to spring in my lib folder which were unused. After I removed that the Application is working fine. Thanks